# How to hide certain components of an activity to use it in various other activities?

Tags: android

I have created a root Activity which has certain components like 6 Spinners with 12-14 items in each. I need to call this activity from other 8 activities(one at a time) but i need to hide certain number of spinners of some of the spinner items for every one of the 8 activities.

Code while calling one of the 8 activities

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Class<? extends Activity> activityToStart = null;

                switch (position){

                    case 0:
                        activityToStart = TownHall1Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        activityToStart = TownHall2Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        activityToStart = TownHall3Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        activityToStart = TownHall4Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        activityToStart = TownHall5Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        activityToStart = TownHall6Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        activityToStart = TownHall7Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        activityToStart = TownHall8Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        activityToStart = TownHall9Activity.class;
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        activityToStart = TownHall10Activity.class;
                        break;

                    case 10:
                        activityToStart = TownHall11Activity.class;
                        break;
//                  
                }

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityToStart);

                startActivity(i);

            }
```

Now each of the above activities call a root activity which consists of 6 spinners and 12 items in each. I need to show different number of spinners or their items for different activity called.

I have heard about set Visibility method.How to use that in this case?

Comment: You should probability consider some sort of design to control a mode or a specific request from your activities to decide WHAT to show or more efficiently what NOT to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send extra to every activity and capture it on your desired activity to know from which activity it is coming

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,YourDesiredActivity.class);
```

i.putExtra("from","main");
startActiity(i);

In SecondActivity in onCreate()

```
String temp=getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
```

if(temp.equlas("main"))
   spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);

hope it helps.

Comment: if i set a particular spinner eg sp1 to sp1.setVisibility(View.GONE); The app crashes when i open the desired activity of spinners. Is it because there is still java coding of that spinner and onItemSelectedListener attached to it?

Comment: and i used this method

//In first activity

 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityToStart);
                    i.putExtra("classFrom", TownHall8Activity.class.toString());
                    startActivity(i);

//in 2nd activity

 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
          if (bundle.getString("classFrom").equals(TownHall8Activity.class.toString())) {

              sp6.setVisibility(View.GONE);

          }